# Finding the average age of all students enrolled in each different class

Tags: sql

I am having trouble figuring out how instead of finding one single average for all the students enrolled in any classes, how to find the average's for each class that has students enrolled.

It is equivalent to finding each class that does have a student enrolled, calculate the sum, calculate the average, then move on to the next class which enrolled students. Then let's say there are three classes that have students enrolled in it, let's output those average ages for each of the three classes. Three results should be returned, not one.

What I thought about initially as an attempted solution

```
SELECT AVG(AGE) FROM STUDENTS;
```

The schema I am using is listed below, with primary keys highlighted in bold.

- Students (**sid: integer**, name: string, major: string, age: integer)
- Enrollment (**sid: integer**, **cid: integer**)
- Classes (**cid: integer**, name: string, instructor: string, room: string, time: time)

Any help is appreciated, greatly.

Finding the average age of all students enrolled in that class.

Sample Data - Students

```
INSERT INTO `Students` (`sid`, `name`, `major`, `age`) VALUES ('1', 'Raymond', 'CS', '20');
INSERT INTO `Students` (`sid`, `name`, `major`, `age`) VALUES ('2', 'Jack', 'CS', '22');
INSERT INTO `Students` (`sid`, `name`, `major`, `age`) VALUES ('3', 'Henry', 'CS', '21');
```

Sample Data - Enrollment

```
INSERT INTO `Enrollment` (`sid`, `cid`) VALUES ('1', '1');
INSERT INTO `Enrollment` (`sid`, `cid`) VALUES ('1', '2');
INSERT INTO `Enrollment` (`sid`, `cid`) VALUES ('2', '2');
```

Sample Data - Classes

```
INSERT INTO `Classes` (`cid`, `name`, `instructor`, `room`, `time`) VALUES ('1', 'Math', 'Jack Brown', '300', '11:20:09');
INSERT INTO `Classes` (`cid`, `name`, `instructor`, `room`, `time`) VALUES ('2', 'Math', 'Henrita Espen', '500', '12:20:09');
```

Database Name - DB

Expected Output - Can vary

If the same student is only one involved, grouping by id will cause an average of the same age.

```
20
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an appropriate database tag.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, working on it.

Comment: The average age of a student enrolled in Henrita Espen's Math class should be 21, shouldn't it? There are two students enrolled: Raymond and Jack. So Raymond's age (20) plus Jack's age (22) gives 42 and 42 divided by 2 (i.e. number of students in class) is 21. Hence your expected output should be: `20 , 21`

Comment: @Abra Student 1 age 20 is enrolled in class 1, he is also the only other person enrolled in class 2 with age of 20. So there is two results of 20. But if you group by id yeah, then you are right one result will be the average.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
select avg(s.age), e.cid
from students s join enrollment e on s.sid = e.sid
group by e.cid
```

Comment: I get what you are stating, I am getting an error involving Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'db.e.cid' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause. But I will look at this and try and get it to work.

Comment: @unfairhistogram I figured out it was the cid for the select and the group by, I got it working. Thanks for the help.